# Nextjs14, shadcnUI and framer motion are not working properly

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, framer-motion, shadcnui

"When using Motion.div, my navbar and footer do not function properly.
Initially, the animations work perfectly. However, upon completing the animation process, the navbar and footer cease to function. Although they remain visible, clicking on links such as 'about,' 'contact,' or any other page does not navigate. Additionally, the dark and light theme functionality is also not working."

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can help you.